# "The windscreen was misting over."

Tags: sentence-structure

> The windscreen was misting over.

What is the parts of speech of *over*, a preposition or an adverb? Why?

Answer (score 1):

From [ldoceonline](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/mist-over)
, **mist over** is a **phrasal verb**:

> 1 if someone’s eyes **mist over**, they become filled with tears

> His eyes **misted over** at the memory of his wife.

[British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/phrasal-verbs) says
phrasal verbs "are made up of a verb and a **particle** or, sometimes, two particles". [emphasis added]

In OP's example,

> The windscreen was misting over.

*over* is a **particle**.

Comment: According to the Cambridge Dictionary website, phrasal verbs are made up of a verb and an adverb particle: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs